# Change default language on ribbon control

Tags: c++, com, ribbon, windows-ribbon-framework

Does anyone know how to change the default language on the ribbon control, I'm using a danish language windows, so the dialogs and standard labels are in danish, but I'm writing the application in english.

I've tried changing the language in the resource file, and tried changing locale with std::locale and setlocale(). But nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself :).

SetThreadPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, L"en-US", NULL);

Did it for me, but only if the specific language pack is fully installed. I hope it'll help someone else.